# The requested URL was not found on this server.

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

i am using amazon aws ec2 and i have installed apache2.
home page are working good but when i click other paste i got this error:

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 80

Comment: is your requested file existing ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a look into my glass spehre, but I bet you have to activate the mod_rewrite-Modul of Apache2.